# WPF windows application - Search

Tags: wpf, search

Urgent help -
I have to implement Search functionality in WPF windows application. In this application, I have a TreeView control, when the user clicks on any TreeViewnode corresponding Wpf user control will appear in right side with data.

I want to implement search. User can enter any thing into Search textbox and that search term should get highlighted in rightside WPF user control.

How can I implement that?

Is there way to show searched term without hitting database.

Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: This question covers too many topics and doesn't give enough details. First you are referring to a master-detail construction that has nothing to to with search. Then you mention search but you do not explain where the items are that you want to search for. And finally you mention a database out of nowhere. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

1) To search any textual item in a WPF view you would have get into the logical and visual tree to get children.

2) Identify the textual properties of each child such as .Text, .Content, .Header.

if an item that carries texual info is found then use

```
    if (<value> is string && ((string)<value>).Contains(searchString))
    { 

       /// Implement step 3 and 4 below.
    }
```

3) Use child.Focus() and child.BringIntoView() calls if one by one search is intended. Otherwise skip to step 4.

4) Use adorners to highlight such item.

Sadly this search will have to be carried using `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke()` and may hang the view if lots of visual items exist.